# What's the difference between name and tbl_name in sqlite_master?

Tags: sqlite, system-tables

What's the difference between `name` and `tbl_name` in `sqlite_master`?

Comment: [The SQLite Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html)  Search for `tbl_name`, This  will lead to an explanation as follow::  _The sqlite_master.tbl_name column holds the name of a table or view that the object is associated with. For a table or view, the tbl_name column is a copy of the name column. For an index, the tbl_name is the name of the table that is indexed. For a trigger, the tbl_name column stores the name of the table or view that causes the trigger to fire._

Answer (score 5):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master), there is no difference if the entry describes a table.
For indexes and triggers, `name` is the name of the object itself, while `tbl_name` is the name of the table that the object belongs to.